# style.display="none" acting wierd - What base am I not covering?

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a a pair of fields (BillingServicesDD & BillingServicesFF). One or the other should be displayed depending on the value of the "SpreadSheet" field. In my onClientLoad event, I do the following;

```
// Set up field hide-when on loading.
spreadSheetVis();
.
(other cool, but unrelated code)
.
}
```

My spreadSheetVis() routine as follows.

```
// set the visibility of our billingservices selection depending on what we
// selected in the spreadsheet value.
function spreadSheetVis() {

  var em = XSP.getElementById("#{id:editMode}");
  if ( em == undefined ) {
    var ss = XSP.getElementById("#{id:SpreadSheetDsp}").innerHTML;
    } else {
    var ss = XSP.getElementById("#{id:Spreadsheet}").value;
    };
  if ( ss === "Compliance") {
    XSP.getElementById("#{id:BillingServicesDD}").style.display = "inline";
    XSP.getElementById("#{id:BillingServicesFF}").style.display = "none";
    } else {
    XSP.getElementById("#{id:BillingServicesDD}").style.display = "none";
    XSP.getElementById("#{id:BillingServicesFF}").style.display = "inline";
    };
}
```

SpreadSheet and BillingServicesDD are both comboboxes. SpreadSheetDSP and BillingServicesFF are both inputTexts. Both SpreadSheet and SpreadSheetDSP point to FInvoiceDoc.Spreadsheet. I use this approach instead of the visible/rendered approach because I need all these values on the form to be available for other pieces of the form. I just don't want selected ones displayed or even taking up real estate when I don't want them seen.

For the most part, this works great. My problem is if I have some kind of validation error when saving the form, then both BillingServicesDD & FF become displayed. The validation error message occurs later in the onClientLoad event with an alert statement if an error message field on the form is set by the server-sided validation routine I wrote.

The field displays are correct all the way through the onClientLoad event and through the alert message (It's the last thing that happens in the onClientLoad event). It's sometime afterwards when the document appears to be re-displayed that both fields appear. (btw, this re-display does not seem to go through the onClientLoad event again.)

Since this is all client-sided code, I run it through IE's debugger. Something strange happens there. All the code runs as it should, but when I step through all the way (even through all that bizzar not-my-code stuff), it says I need to resubmit the doc and then gets caught in a loop where I continuously get my alert error message. I have to kill IE then.

If I have the debugger turned off, this loop doesn't happen.

Comment: display should have a value, such as inline, block, none, etc

Comment: switched to "inline" same thing

Comment: I missed this part: *"when the document appears to be re-displayed"* are you sure the page isn't reloading? a reload would of course reset them back to their default display. What you're seeing in the debugger seems to suggest that it is

Comment: if it was, wouldn't it trip the onClientLoad event again? This is the order. Save button (field styles are correct) -> alert message (field styles still correct) -> hit OK -> form redisplays. Now field styles are incorrect. I am not conciously reloading the document. I have server sided code in the "beforePageLoad" and "afterPageLoad". I have removed any statements there that do any changes to currentDocument. Still getting the same results.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xpages, so i don't know.

Comment: Are you doing a full or partial refresh? Partial refresh does not trigger onClientLoad

Comment: onClientLoad code is client side. Refresh option not available. Both beforePageLoad and afterPageLoad are set to "No Submission" My "Save" button is set to "Full Update"

Comment: That answered my question. If you are doing a full update, then you should be triggering onClientLoad during the reload of the page. You said it was all client-side, but does that include your validation code? It sounds like something is triggering a partial refresh of a container your fields reside in.

Comment: My save button calls a SSJS script library routine called saveDocument. It performs field validations. On a bad value it stores the error message in currentDocument and aborts. onClientLoad event looks for a value in this field. If found, it does an alert with the error message, then depending on the error, sets focus to the appropriate field. onClientLoad fires off fine and the screen shows up with the correct fields when the alert message goes off. In my mind, it should just go back to the form, instead it appears to redispay it a second time but not going through the onClientLoad event.

Comment: I am not sure if this will change anything, but you have a scope problem in your JS code: your variable ss is declared in its own scope and is hence not available for the check for equality to "Compliance".  In fact, in the compliance check you are checking a global variable ss not the one you have set 2 resp. 4 lines above...

Comment: That piece of code appears to be working fine. Ya'know, being from the basic world, I never got a grip on this var thing. (The == and === in conditionals are still bizzare to me and still trips me up from time to time.) So are you saying I should have a "var ss="";" below where em is assigned, then just drop the var after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your approach. Remove the code that tries to hide the fields from your OnLoad event. 
I presume you didn't use the rendered property (which wouldn't send the field in the first place) since you need it in some computations.

Go to the all properties panel of the field, locate the style property and enter a SSJS expression that computes visibility or display property.

Putting the calculation there will survive any refresh.

A sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:checkBox text="Control on" id="editMode"
        value="#{viewScope.editMode}" checkedValue="true"
        uncheckedValue="false" defaultChecked="true">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="SpreadSheetDsp">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:checkBox>

    <xp:table style="width:100.0%" id="SpreadSheetDsp">
        <xp:tr style="background-color : #FFBBBB">
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:"false" != viewScope.editMode;}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            <xp:td>Visible</xp:td>
            <xp:td>when checked</xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr style="background-color : #BBBBFF">
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:"false" == viewScope.editMode;}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            <xp:td>Visible</xp:td>
            <xp:td>when unchecked</xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
</xp:view>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That's what I thought. Do you have an example of a SSJS expression that changes a field's style property? Just something general to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I get it now. I decided to use the styleClass piece. Used a computed value for the field with if (currentDocument.getValue("Compliance")) {"xspHiddenFieldsDiv"} else {"xspUnhideField"}

Comment: Added a sample. This will not send the markup down, unless you need it, then go with the styleClass